# How I can signing the wsdl attribute with X509 certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, soap-client

I have a wsdl file and xsd.

So I have create a new Jva Project, then I have import wsdl file, generate the Test Client.

Now I must to call a SOAP WebService. To do this I can connect throws ssl certificate (I have do this) and I must signing 5 attribute into wsdl file.

How can I signing these attribute with X509 certificate?